# Difference between CPU and processor

Tags: cpu

Is there any difference between the terms 'Central Processing Unit' and 'Processor,' or are the terms interchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangeable, but would need to be in context to what your expressing.

Eg. The computers processor is 3Ghz or I'm putting carrots in the processor.